# How to send API response as JSON object to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The response is a JSON object from a dictionary API. The response successfully logs to the console. How to send the JSON object contained in the response back to client?

```
router.get('/dictionary_test', (req, res, next) => {
  const lookup = dict.find("apple");
  lookup.then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
});
```

Comment: You're shadowing the `res` variable. You can do `.then(dictResult => res.json(dictResult))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `res.json()` when you have the data.  And make sure you aren't hiding the parent `res` by accidentally defining another local argument of the same name (note the change to `result` so it doesn't conflict with `res`):

```
router.get('/dictionary_test', (req, res, next) => {
  const lookup = dict.find("apple");
  lookup.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    res.json(result);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });
});
```